# Check a PHP Time(H:i:s) reside between two times(H:i:s)

Tags: php

Suppose,

```
$at_time = '07:45:00';

$ranges = [
   ['start' => '09:00:00', 'end' => '17:00:00'],
   ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '08:59:00']
];
```

Now I want to check that `$ranges` contain the `$at_time` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My PHP is a bit rusty, but try something like:

```
$matches=Array();

foreach($ranges as $i=>$ikey){
    if(strtotime($ranges[$i]['start']) < strtotime($at_time) && strtotime($ranges[$i]['end']) > strtotime($at_time)){
         array_push($matches,$i);
    }
}
```

Then `$matches` will contain an array of all the ranges which contain the `$at_time`.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: inspired by the answer of @Jimmery above.**

You can put it into a function which returns the *matched range* or *false* - additionally it has the small advantage that it stops with the first match:

```
function timeInRange($at_time,$ranges)
{
    foreach($ranges as $i=>$ikey)
    {
        if(strtotime($ranges[$i]['start']) < strtotime($at_time) && strtotime($ranges[$i]['end']) > strtotime($at_time))
        {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
<?php

function arrayContainsTime($time, $ranges) {
    $target = strtotime($time);
    foreach($ranges as $range) {
        $start  = strtotime($range['start']);
        $end    = strtotime($range['end']);

        if($target > $start && $target < $end) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

$at_time      = '07:45:00';
$another_time = '10:30:45';

$ranges = [
   ['start' => '09:00:00', 'end' => '17:00:00'],
   ['start' => '17:00:00', 'end' => '08:59:00']
];


echo $at_time, " match? ", arrayContainsTime($at_time, $ranges);
echo "<br>";
echo $another_time, " match? ", arrayContainsTime($another_time, $ranges);
```

[See it in action here!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hx2a5m)

Notice: It won't detect 17:00:00 -> 08:59:00 correctly, because no date is included.

Comment: I moved the `$target` initialization out of the loop, since it remains the same during.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a way

```
$time = str_replace(":","",$at_time);
foreach($ranges as $rangleval){
    $start = str_replace(":","",$rangleval['start']);
    $end = str_replace(":","",$rangleval['end']);
        if($start<=$time && $end>=$time){
            echo $at_time." lies between ".$rangleval['start']." and ".$rangleval['end'];
            break;
        }
    }
```